# Error while try to make widget to the form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I get an error when I try to add a widget to the form.

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 558, in __init__
super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

The model

```
class Video(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post-videos')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    video_poster = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to='post-videos')
```

The views

```
def VideosUploadView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    all_videos = Video.objects.all()
    V_form = Video_form()
    video_added = False
    
    if not request.user.is_active:
        # any error you want
        return redirect('login')
    
    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    except:
        # any error you want
        return HttpResponse('User does not exits.')
    
    if 'submit_v_form' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        V_form = Video_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if V_form.is_valid():
            instance = V_form.save(commit=False)
    
            instance.author = account
            instance.save()
            V_form = Video_form()
            video_added = True
    
    contex = {
        'all_videos': all_videos,
        'account': account,
        'V_form': V_form,
        'video_added': video_added,
    }

return render(request, "video/upload_videos.html", contex)
```

The form

class Video_form(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Video
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'video', 'video_poster')

    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'video': forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})),
        'video_poster': forms.ImageField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),


    }
```

Comment: can you show the full error traceback

Comment: The local sever disconnect duo to this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign valid widget in the `Video_form`:

```
widgets = {
    'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    'video': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    'video_poster': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
}
```

`forms.FileField` and `forms.ImageField` are fields not widgets.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was style the form fields and I explored a good way to styling the fields by add the field name after the form name
Like this way

```
    <span class="control-fileupload">
             <!--here what I mean--> {{ V_form.video }}
              <label for="file1" class="text-left">click to choose a Video on your computer.</label>
            </span>
```

and here also

```
<label>{{ V_form.title }}</label>
```